# CosmosDB Gremlin API alternative for storing and processing Graph data

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, graph-databases, gremlin, graph-traversal, azure-cosmosdb-gremlinapi

I currently use **CosmosDB Gremlin API** to store nodes and edges of an organization chart. To keep the data and occasional traversal, it is costing me minimum of $20 every month. Is there an alternative to **CosmosDB Gremlin API** which is cheaper and can be used to store nodes and edges and then traverse/process them also. I will have more organizational charts in the future, so want to keep the cost under control. Can this be achieved with **Azure Table Storage** and algorithms in C# rather than depending on a specialized Graph Database like **Gremlin**?

Answer (score 0):

Surely you could describe organization chart in Azure Table Storage,you have to sort out the relationship between the characters.But the most embarrassing thing is that you can't use Gremlin's query method any more which loses the charm of graphical database.

If you think the cosmos db gremlin api cost is unacceptable for you,maybe you could balance these databases which is listed in the gremlin official [document](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/) and choose a more economical db.

[image]

Comment: Table Storage cannot represent graph data, without costly partition/table scans (or having to create additional tables for different traversal needs). Also, please note that product recommendation questions are off-topic and often lead to debate and spam. Posting a link to a list of graph databases doesn't really fit here.